# Removing 0 at the end of multiple time series

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have multiple time series stored in a Spark DataFrame as below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-03-10', 'France', 19),
                            ('2020-03-11', 'France', 22),
                            ('2020-03-12', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-03-13', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-03-14', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'UK', 12),
                            ('2020-04-11', 'UK', 0),
                            ('2020-04-12', 'UK', 9),
                            ('2020-04-13', 'UK', 0),
                            ('2020-04-08', 'Japan', 0),
                            ('2020-04-09', 'Japan', -3),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'Japan', -2)
                           ],
                           ['date', 'country', 'y']
                           )
```

I am looking for a way (without looping as my real DataFrame has millions of rows) to remove the 0's at the end of each time series.

In our example, we would obtain:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-03-10', 'France', 19),
                            ('2020-03-11', 'France', 22),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'UK', 12),
                            ('2020-04-11', 'UK', 0),
                            ('2020-04-12', 'UK', 9),
                            ('2020-04-08', 'Japan', 0),
                            ('2020-04-09', 'Japan', -3),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'Japan', -2)
                           ],
                           ['date', 'country', 'y']
                           )
```

Comment: Is this not zero? `('2020-04-08', 'Japan', 0)`, your output and question doesn't match.

Comment: filter with `y != 0`

Comment: I think the goal is to remove the values ending with zero for every country. if it is in the middle or start, we leave it, hence the japan stays. Atleast what I assumed for my answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you want to remove at the end of every country ordered by date

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-03-10', 'France', 19),
                            ('2020-03-11', 'France', 22),
                            ('2020-03-12', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-03-13', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-03-14', 'France', 0),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'UK', 12),
                            ('2020-04-11', 'UK', 0),
                            ('2020-04-12', 'UK', 9),
                            ('2020-04-13', 'UK', 0),
                            ('2020-04-13', 'India', 1),
                            ('2020-04-14', 'India', 0),
                            ('2020-04-15', 'India', 0),
                            ('2020-04-16', 'India', 1),
                            ('2020-04-08', 'Japan', 0),
                            ('2020-04-09', 'Japan', -3),
                            ('2020-04-10', 'Japan', -2)
                           ],
                           ['date', 'country', 'y']
                           )
# convert negative to positive to avoid accidental summing up to 0
df=df.withColumn('y1',F.abs(F.col('y')))
# Window function to reverse the last rows to first
w=Window.partitionBy('country').orderBy(F.col('date').desc())
# Start summing function. when the first non zero value comes the value changes
df_sum = df.withColumn("sum_chk",F.sum('y1').over(w))
# Filter non zero values, sort it just for viewing
df_res = df_sum.where("sum_chk!=0").orderBy('date',ascending=True)
```

The result:

```
    df_res.show()
+----------+-------+---+---+-------+
|      date|country|  y| y1|sum_chk|
+----------+-------+---+---+-------+
|2020-03-10| France| 19| 19|     41|
|2020-03-11| France| 22| 22|     22|
|2020-04-08|  Japan|  0|  0|      5|
|2020-04-09|  Japan| -3|  3|      5|
|2020-04-10|  Japan| -2|  2|      2|
|2020-04-10|     UK| 12| 12|     21|
|2020-04-11|     UK|  0|  0|      9|
|2020-04-12|     UK|  9|  9|      9|
|2020-04-13|  India|  1|  1|      2|
|2020-04-14|  India|  0|  0|      1|
|2020-04-15|  India|  0|  0|      1|
|2020-04-16|  India|  1|  1|      1|
+----------+-------+---+---+-------+
```